# Regexp to capture overlapping matches

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regexp option or trick to capture all possible strings in a regexp when matches can overlap.

Example : `/A.A/` in string `"ABACADA"`

It finds : `ABA, ADA` and not `ACA` !!

I would like : `ABA, ACA, ADA`

I am working in PHP, but it can be applied to other languages

```
preg_match_all('/A.A/',"ABACADA",$matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
// output : array (size=2)
// 0 => string 'ABA' (length=3)
// 1 => string 'ADA' (length=3)
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: just use  a lookahead `(?=(A.A))` see http://regex101.com/r/wU8uM7/18

Comment: @AvinashRaj: That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: IMO lookahead is common factor but this is a PHP problem not a Python one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get all 3 matches:

```
(?=(A.A))
```

**[RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zY2fE2/1)**

For your input it finds 3 matches in **captured group #1**:

1. `ABA`
2. `ACA`
3. `ADA`

**PHP Code:**

```php
if (preg_match_all('/(?=(A.A))/', "ABACADA", $m))
   print_r($m[1]); // printing index 1
```

**Output:**

```php
Array
(
    [0] => ABA
    [1] => ACA
    [2] => ADA
)
```